# Maximise and Minimise Calendar jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have created a Calendar.But,I have issues in maximising it to full screen.please,can any one help me in doing this.

```
$("#panel-fullscreen").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $this = $(this);

    if ($this.children('i').hasClass('glyphicon-resize-full')) {
        $this.children('i').removeClass('glyphicon-resize-full');
        $this.children('i').addClass('glyphicon-resize-small');
    } else if ($this.children('i').hasClass('glyphicon-resize-small')) {
        $this.children('i').removeClass('glyphicon-resize-small');
        $this.children('i').addClass('glyphicon-resize-full');
    }
    $(this).closest('.panel').toggleClass('panel-fullscreen');
});
```

[codepen link](http://codepen.io/SantoshNeela/pen/qadkGN)

Comment: what is the issue?

Comment: calendar is not maximising to fullscreen

Comment: `panel-fullscreen` class is getting assigned to `.panel` correctly. and CSS like top:0 , left: 0 is getting set correctly via that. So i think you are missing further CSS to maximize each and every row and column

Comment: ok,I will add css and check... Thanks for your response